How to control text in an EventLog event
I'm trying to cheat with the EventLog in a C++ application. I have no message file; I simply use RegisterEventSource() and ReportEvent() in a sequence.
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    LPCWSTR pInsertStrings[1] = { NULL };

    HANDLE hEventLog = RegisterEventSource(NULL, L"AaaAaa");
    if (NULL == hEventLog) exit(0);

    Sleep(200);

    // This event uses insert strings.
    pInsertStrings[0] = L"Test event from AaaAaa";
    ReportEvent(hEventLog, EVENTLOG_INFORMATION_TYPE, /*cat*/ 100, 
        /*evId*/ 0, /*uId*/ NULL, /*msgs*/ 1, 
        /*msgSz*/ 0, (LPCWSTR*)pInsertStrings, /*data*/ NULL);
}

Almost everything works as expected. The event pops up in the EventLog and contains all the pieces I have sent in in the call to ReportEvent().

However, the text string I sent in the call only shows up in the Details pane of the Event Properties popup.

How can I cheaply get this text into the General pane?
I understand that the parameter dwEventID in the call to ReportEvent() controls the text in the General pane. But I know it is possible to control this text in some other way, still free from the complexity of the message file.
How can you do it?

"I have no message file" - sorry, you need a message file. But, you can use your app's .exe as the message file if you store the messages in its resources.  Register your .exe in the EventLog Registry, and create a message for Event ID 0 that has its content set to %1, then it can display the string you pass in to ReportEvent(). See https://stackoverflow.com/a/37417612/65863

@Remy Lebeau: Thank you.  I do know this is the normal solution. In a C#/.NET app I produce elegant events without the message file (the messy file). I insist you can do it in C++ as well. But I don't remember how.

What I described is how I do it when using ReportEvent() in C++, and it works fine (and is the only way I've been able to get it to work, without creating a separate message file or DLL). I'm guessing the C# approach is not based on ReportEvent() (since it is a deprecated API since Vista).

@Remy Lebeau: So I'm trying to use a deprecated API? The compiler didn't tell me it. What are the valid calls? In C#/.NET I use EvenLog.WriteEntry(). It's similar. You can also create the entry in the registry.

"deprecated" in the fact that there are newer APIs (ie, manifest-based, etc) that Microsoft wants people to use instead. ReportEvent() is not actually marked "deprecated" in the compiler, but it is an old API. In any case, C#'s EventLog.WriteEntry() calls ReportEvent() using a Microsoft-provided message file that simply displays the 1st insertion string passed to ReportEvent(), like I described earlier (you can see the source code for yourself on https://referencesource.microsoft.com).

@RemyLebeau How does .NET register that? Looking at the managed EventLog.WriteEntry(), it still requires an EventID, which when you trace the source is eventually passed to the native ReportEvent(..., eventID, ...); And the native API notes that eventID: "The event identifier. The event identifier specifies the entry in the message file associated with the event source. "  How do they manage the magic if i pass an eventID of 1337, that it gets successfully mapped to an entry in a message file that does not exist? In other words: how can i steal what .NET does in native code.

If you follow the C# source code for EventLog.WriteEntry(), you will see it call VerifyAndCreateSource() to register an event source and message file EventLogMessages.dll for the calling app. That DLL is provided by the .NET framework. And if you look inside that DLL, it has a MESSAGETABLE resource with entries for all possible event IDs 0-65535, and each one is set to "%1\r\n\x00". So, the same technique I described earlier. If you want to replicate that, simply create your own message table resource for your event IDs, inside your EXE file if you don't want a separate DLL.

The program below shows a proposed solution for the problem. Instead of using WINAPI for access to the Event Log, the program uses .NET functions.
#using <system.dll>
#using <mscorlib.dll>
#include <winsock2.h>

using namespace System;
using namespace System::Diagnostics;

int main()
{
    String^ sSource = gcnew String("TestLog");
    String^ sLog = gcnew String("Application");
    String^ sEvent = gcnew String("Sample event message from EvenLogTest");

    try
    {
        if (!EventLog::SourceExists(sSource))
            EventLog::CreateEventSource(sSource, sLog);
    }
    catch (Exception^ e) {
        MessageBox(nullptr, L"Run this program once as Administrator",
            L"EventLogTest", MB_OK | MB_SYSTEMMODAL | MB_ICONERROR);
        exit(0);
    }

    EventLog::WriteEntry(sSource, sEvent);
}

The program shows a complete test solution. At the first execution, the program installs in the registry the log source TestLog under Application. This operation requires administrator privileges. If the program is not started by the administrator, it displays the corresponding message in a MessageBox and quits. Subsequent program executions do not require any privileges and are used to insert further events into the log.
To compile this program in Visual Studio, the parameter  Properties->Configuration Properties->Advanced->Common Language Runtime Support must be set to .NET Framework Runtime Support (/clr). Consequently, the compiler uses the Common Language version of C++ rather than the native C++. This may lead to a mix of CLR and native C++ and cause collisions. As an example, #include <iostream> generates non-stopping compilation errors, and its functionality should preferably be replaced with equivalent .NET functions.
The proposed solution is more complex than the original program, both due to the language complications and the need to run it once by the administrator. The advantage is that it provides control over the text in the event's General pane. By comparison, the original program is much simpler, but the event text is only visible in the Details pane, while the General pane shows some hard to control standard text.
I would not consider creating my own message file (.NET functions do use a message file). It's unnecessary and complex. There is a reason why the .NET implementation has removed this burden from the user.

"It's unnecessary and complex." - It is neither. Why are you hell-bent on avoiding The Solution?

@IInspectable: Hi IInspectable, nice to see you again. I'm done with my app. It logs events and does everything else. It has less than 150 lines. The only tool I'm using is the VS C++ compiler and linker. I haven't studied message files in detail, but I noted that you use new syntax, new tools, and a manual operation in the registry. It's just a ridiculous increase in complexity for a 150-line app. In comparison, my approach is very smooth.
